# How do I add element from an existing document to a new document?

Tags: java, xml, dom

For my case, I need to take some nodes from the existing XML file and create a new document and add the all nodes that are in existing file.

How do I add element from an existing document to a new document?

Comment: NodeList list = doc.getElementsByTagName("SUBJECTS");
StreamResult result = new StreamResult("d:\\sample.txt") ;
for (int i=0; i<list.getLength(); i++){
  Element element = (Element)list.item(i);
  DOMSource source = new DOMSource(element) ;
  Result dest = new StreamResult(System.out);
  aTransformer.transform(source, dest);
  aTransformer.transform(source, result) ; }

Comment: this is the code i added in my class.

Comment: i have two element. but in my document only added the last document. not previous one. can u help me?

Answer (score 0):

Likely problem is that you tried to insert node to the target document without importing it. Importing node to target document is done via [Document.importNode](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Document.html#importNode%28org.w3c.dom.Node,%20boolean%29). Code is roughly as follows, of course exact location in target document should be changed specific to you application:

```
    NodeList list ...
    for(int i=0; i < list.getLength(); i++){
        Node nodeToImport = list.item(i);
        Node importedNode = targetDocument.importNode(nodeToImport, true);
        targetDocument.getDocumentElement().appendChild(importedNode);
    }
```

Comment: but it causes NullPointerException.